# Selecting balls from infinite sample with certain conditions

Tags: permutations, combinations, combinatorial-geometry

What are the number of ways of selecting 10 balls from the unlimited number of red, green, white and yellow balls, if selection must include 2 red and 3 yellow balls ? (Order doesn't matter)
Sorry, I have no idea. Please help me to solve it

Comment: does the order matter or not?  Assuming it does not, then I think that [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is a good way to proceed here.  You are counting $4-$ tuples $(r,g,w,y)$ of non-negative integers that add to $5$ (it's $5$, not $10$ because five of the balls are pre-assigned).

Comment: No, order doesn't matter. I have gone through Stars and Bars a bit. But here, there is a condition also that 2 red and 3 yellow balls must be there. How to account for these ?

Comment: As I explained, we already have those five balls assigned.  To illustrate, pick some $4-$tuple that adds to $5$.  Lets say $(1,0,2,2)$.  These describe the unassigned balls...one red, no green, two white, two yellow.  Adding to the pre-assigned balls we get three red, no green, two white, five yellow as your final choice.  Sticking to coordinate notation, just add $(2,0,0,3)$ to your $4-$ tuple that adds to $5$.  In my example you get $(1,0,2,2)+(2,0,0,3)=(3,0,2,5)$.

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate that order does not matter...the problem is considerably harder if you include order.

Comment: Do you want exactly or at least 2 reds and 3 yellows?

Comment: at least 2 reds and 3 yellows